# How to add document uploaded data from contact form 7 to ZOHO CRM?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, zoho

I integrate ZOHO API with contact form 7 already and it is working fine but I also want to get attachment data to my Zoho CRM. Can anyone please help me with this doubt?

Please refer to the code below that I have already done -

Any one please help me to get information how to get attachment in zoho crm from contact form 7

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','brainium_cf7_api_sender');
function brainium_cf7_api_sender($contact_form){

    $title = $contact_form->title;

    if( $title === 'Contact form 1') {
       $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if( $submission ){
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

            $first_name = $posted_data['first-name'];
            $last_name = $posted_data['last-name'];
            $email = $posted_data['your-email'];
            $phone = $posted_data['Phone-no'];
            $message = $posted_data['your-message'];
            $budget = $posted_data['budget'];
            $checkbox = $posted_data['checkbox-628'][0];
            $noc = $posted_data['checkbox-730'][0];
                              
            $documents= $posted_data['file-714'];

            $auth = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
            $refreshToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            //get the last date and time of refresh token generation
            
            //get the access token
            $url = "https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token";
            $query = "refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=refresh_token";
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            //get the token from the JSON in result
            $accessToken =  json_decode($result, true);
            //echo ($accessToken['access_token']); 
            //die();        
            
            $data = array("First_Name"=>$first_name, "Last_Name"=>$last_name, "Email"=>$email, "Phone"=>$phone, "Description"=>($message), "Budget"  => $budget, 'Subscribed_Newsletter' => $checkbox, 'Company' => $noc, 'Documents' => $documents , "Lead_Date"=>$zoho_date, '$gclid'=>$zc_gad);
            //$data = json_encode($data);
            
            $encodedData = array();
            $encodedData['data'][0] = $data;
            
            //var_dump($data);
            //echo(json_encode($encodedData));
            //die();
            //che


            $url ="https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads";
            $headers = array(
                                'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken '.$accessToken['access_token'],
                                'Content-Type:application/json'
                            );

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($encodedData));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            //echo $result;
            // End zoho CRM
            $success = true;
            $msg = 'Done';
            
            $leadSaving = print_r($result, true);
            $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . $email;
            $leadSaving = $leadSaving . "\r\n" . "request quote";
            file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", $leadSaving, FILE_APPEND);
            file_put_contents("lead-zoho-entry-status.txt", "\r\n\r\n", FILE_APPEND); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `$uploadedFiles = $submission->uploaded_files();` will get you the attachments.  Also, I would use `wp_remote_post` rather than `curl`

Comment: hi can you please mention where exactly this code will go?